# DefaultAppPool set to ApplicationPoolIdentity won't work

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, sql-server-2012-express

I built a WCF Data Service hosted in an ASP NET App that runs with IIS 7.

**I'm able to access this service from other computers across the network just fine**.

The thing is that I have DefaultAppPool set to NetwrokService, if I set it to ApplicationPoolIdentity, then the connection between Wpf Applications and the Data Service breaks.

Why?, In SQL Server Express 2012 I'm using "NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red" ("Servicio de red" is "Network Service" in spanish) mapped to my database.

I understand that NetworkService is present in IIS7 for compatibility with previous versions, and IIS7 introduced ApplicationPoolIdentity to increase security since many applications use NetworkService.

That´s why I´d like to be able to use this ApplicationPoolIdentity but I don't know what setting is necessary for it to work.

My authentication setting is:

[image]

Rafael

Comment: What is the error you get?  Did you right click on Anonymous Authentication and choose to use ApplicationPoolIdentity rather than IUSR?

Comment: The error is "Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool". Anonymous Authentication has always been Application Pool Identity. I never changed that

Comment: If you refuse to share the error you're getting, we can't help you.

Comment: Thank you Erik for answering. Could you please reply an answer so I can Mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool to the users in SQL Server? (I assume your SQL Server is on the same machine as the IIS server? If not, then you have to add your computer name from the domain)